# What other decentralized bitcoin / altcoin exchanges are there besides Bitsquare?

Tags: exchanges, altcoin, alternatives

I recently found out about Bitsquare's decentralized exchange that lets you trade altcoin or fiat. But are there other decentralized altcoin exchanges out there like bitsquare?

Comment: Bitsquare (now called Bisq) is the most active and usable.  There are various projects on Ethereum, but I don't think they support Fiat and most are very new / limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try https://localbitcoins.com
It is a p2p crypto exchange market that allows you to interact and exchange currencies with your counter-party directly, no intermediaries.

See also:

- https://0xproject.com
- https://etherdelta.com